# Upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 has stucked

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, 15.04

I am upgrading from `14.10` to `15.04` but something goes wrong. The process has stopped. I guess I must `accept` something or `agree` with something but I am not able to see what exactly.

[image]

I try pressing `tab`, `shift`, `control` + `shift` and `enter` but nothing changed. I am not able to expand the `terminal` window, too.

Should I restart the `PC` and run the upgrade again?

Comment: How did you solve the problem? Maybe it was a window in the background?