# Upgrade from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 hangs with grayed out Distribution Upgrade window

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, kubuntu, 14.10

Today I attempted to upgrade from Kubuntu 14.10 to Kubuntu 15.04 on a ThinkPad X250 notebook following this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VividUpgrades/Kubuntu

I came to the dialog box asking to confirm "Package Changes". I selected "Start Upgrade". The upgraded started but now it is stuck. I can see the window "Distribution Upgrade" but it is greyed out. It's like that for at least 6 hours now. I think the last thing I saw before the window was greyed out was something like "configuring... systemd"

Kubuntu is still responding. I have a notification that uppdates are available for my system. `lsb_release -a` shows:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` all repositories point to `vivid universe`.

Something similar seems to have happened [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275076). But this guy restarted his system and had to perform a fresh install. 
[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/613779/458355) could be a similar issue, but there the distribution upgrade window was not grayed out. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614005/upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04-stuck) the upgrade was stuck but opposed to there I cannot see the terminal. [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/615124/458355) is also different as it hangs somewhere else. However, following but I followed the idea to check with `ps` which processes might be running:

```
$ ps -ef | grep upgrade
root      2877  1659  3 14:23 ?        00:12:27 /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uirakud8/vivid --mode=desktop --frontend=DistUpgradeViewKDE
```

If I try to close the Distribution Upgrade window a Warning appears:

```
Application "ubuntu-release-upgrader" is not responding
You tried to close window "Distribution Upgrade" from application "ubuntu-release-upgrader" (Process ID: 2586) but the application is not responding.
Do you want to terminate this application? 
Warning: Terminating the application will close all of its child windows. Any unsaved data will be lost.
```

What should I do to finish the upgrade? Is it safe to restart my computer and try again?

Comment: Have you also Unity installed? Compiz isn't necessary for KDE. Try to remove the compiz packages in tty1 (Ctrl-Alt-F1).

Comment: No I do not have unity. In fact, compiz-core is not even installed. I should check for the other packages. Ctrl-Alt-F1 works when the boot hangs at `starting version 219`. Thanks!

Comment: Start the Recovery Mode in Grub. You can find this menu entry behind Advanced.

Comment: I do not have `compiz-core` or `compiz-gnome` installed.

Comment: Other `compiz` packages? `dpkg -l | grep compiz`

Comment: No, no other `compiz` packages. `dpkg -l | grep compiz` shows nothing.

Comment: Maybe, http://askubuntu.com/q/614198/458355 is solution for `starting version 219`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix it. In the end I basically upgraded to 15.10 without getting 15.04 to run properly. First I killed the upgrade process:

```
$sudo kill 2877
$sudo dpkg --configure -a

Configuration file '/etc/systemd/logind.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** logind.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I had manually edited `logind.conf` before, so this question makes sense. Maybe, this was the point where the upgrade was stuck.  I answered `Y`.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

gave the following message:

```
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

then I performed an upgrade of my packages using `aptitude`. Which gave me the following errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqgpgme1
 kde-telepathy-auth-handler
 kdepim-kresources
 cups-browsed
 cups-daemon
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
 hplip
 printer-driver-hpcups
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
```

I removed exactly those packages using `aptitude` and performed another upgrade. This one did not show errors. The I performed another upgrade. 
Then I rebooted my machine but it hangs while booting. It says `starting version 219` on the screen.

I installed the package `xinit`. I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to select lightdm as the default window manager. Now I'm able to see the login screen for a second until the screen turns black. I switched back to sddm: I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` and selected sddm.

Then I booted into root console and performed `do-release-upgrade`. This did hang after a while. Then, I upgraded all packages with `aptitude`. After 2 or 3 reboots I can now login to KDE again.